# Как правильно использовать wall.post api vk attachments

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как правильно использовать параметр `attachments` на api vk метод `wall.post` в php делаю так:

```
$user_wall = $vk->api('wall.post', array(
        'owner_id'      => '197240174',
        'friends_only'  => '0',
        'message'       => 'name',
        'access_token'  => $token,
        'attachments' => '<type>photo-http://gd3.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/3003094957/TB2pDa5aA1M.eBjSZFFXXc3vVXa_!!3003094957.jpg'
    ));
```

а именно надо постить изображения по ссылке. Без загрузки в вк

Comment: Так нельзя, надо обязательно сперва загрузить на вк

Comment: В интернете есть скрипт загрузки с получением ссылки. Скачиваете к себе на сервер фотку, загружаете ее в вк, получаете ссылку, публикуете и удаляете сразу фотку с сервера.

Comment: а готовую можно найти такую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я использую такой код для сохранения фотографии на сервере ВК и получении ее ссылки. В переменной `$fok` и будет необходимая ссылка на картинку, для вставки в `attachments`

```html
file_put_contents('1.jpg', file_get_contents(//линк на фотку)); //Сохраняем картинку к себе
      $tok = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; ///Токен
      $myidgr = 'xxxxxxx'; ///ID или домен группы - паблика
      $imga = '1.jpg'; ///Картинка для постинга


///Получаем разрешение на загрузку картинки Вконтакте
   $getwall = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?group_id='.$myidgr.'&access_token='.$tok;
   $dl = file_get_contents($getwall);
   $dl = json_decode($dl); ///Декодируем json
   $dl = $dl->response->upload_url; ///Получаем ссылку загрузки от Вконтакте
   
            $file = new CURLFile(realpath("$imga")); ///Загружаем картинку
            $ch = curl_init($dl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('photo' => $file));
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            
///Получаем данные для сохранения картинки             
            $fot = $data; ///Получаем данные из массива
            $fot = json_decode($data); ///Декодируем json
            $fot = $fot->photo; ///Получаем данные из массива

            $hash = json_decode($data); ///Декодируем json
            $hash = $hash->hash; ///Получаем данные из массива

            $serv = json_decode($data); ///Декодируем json
            $serv = $serv->server; ///Получаем данные из массива


///Сохраняем фото на сервер Вконтакте
$savephoto = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto?group_id='.$myidgr.'&hash='.$hash.'&server='.$serv.'&photo='.$fot.'&access_token='.$tok;
      $result = file_get_contents($savephoto);
      $fok = json_decode($result); ///Декодируем json
      $fok = $fok->response->id; ///Получаем данные из массива


///Вырезаем данные из информации после сохранения на сервер (Использовать если не работает переменная // $result)
         $fok = substr($result, strpos($result,'"id":"')+6, strlen($result)); ///Отрезаем начало до photo
unlink('1.jpg'); //Удаляем картинку
```